# Python : using function

Tags: linux, python-2.7, python-idle

how I can make function in program like IDLE or linux terminal?
and how I can use loop? when I am trying to use it that happen:

```
>>>for i in numbers:  # when i am push enter its make ... 
...    print packet[i]  # when i am pushing on the enter its create new line
```

Comment: you just need to press enter again to execute your for loop - try `for i in range(10): print i` to give you a flavour.

Comment: thank you very much, what about functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is defined like this:

```
def my_func(arg_one):
    return arg_one * 2

print my_func(2)

4
```

I thoroughly recommend the Python [tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) as a great place to get started learning Python.

And you can simulate a loop in your interpreter like this:

```
>>> for i in range(5): # press enter
...    print i         # press enter again
...                    # press enter again
...
0
1
2
3
4
>>>
```

Note the use of `#` which is the proper way to start a line comment in Python too.

Comment: if my line is very long how can I continue it in under line?

Comment: this is a new question really ... however, you can use the `\\` character at the end of a line to carry it onto the next line :)

Comment: @ariel20:  I second the suggestion to start through the tutorial.  All the questions you have asked are explained there. That is how I started 19 years ago.